# Upsert nested objects in mongodb 3.2 using Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb-java

I'm trying to use the upsert feature of mongodb **v3.2** using **java**,
so every solution not including a java response would not be accepted.

My problem is that the upsert command override nested objects instead of adding new ones, I have tried to use '*$addToSet*' and '*push*', but without success and I get an error message indicating that the storage engine does not support this command.

I want to update the client's document as well as their inner objects such as checks and checks's values.
the global structure of the client doc is as below.

```
Client
 |
 |__Checks // array of checks , update or insert operation
    |
    |__values // array of values, every check has its own values (20 max)
              // update using index(id)
```

link of the: [**Example's source code**](https://github.com/BenRhouma/MongoUpsert4Stackoverflow.git)

My intention is to use only one query to update client's document without using many queries.

I'm not specialist in mongodb, so every advice or critics would be appreciated.

Even if I'm doing this all wrong, feel free to notify me, and please using **java** for mongo **3.2**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the source code used to generate the last result.

```java
package org.egale.core;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOptions;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.bson.Document;

/**
 *
 * @author Zied
 */
public class MongoTest {

    /**
     * Pojo used to populate data
     */
    static class CheckModel {
        public String client;
        public String checkId;
        public String name;
        public String command;
        public String description;
        public String topic;
        public int refresh = 60;
        public int status;
        public String output;
    }

    static MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    static String dbName = "eagle";

    private static List<Document> getCheckValues(CheckModel checkModel, int index) {

        final List<Document> checkValues = new ArrayList<>();
        final Document val = new Document()
                .append("id", index)
                .append("output", checkModel.output)
                .append("status", checkModel.status);
        checkValues.add(val); // second execution should not ovveride the content of value but a new 
        return checkValues;
    }

    private static void insertCheck(MongoDatabase db, CheckModel checkModel) {
        int idx =++index % 20;
        final List<Document> checks = new ArrayList<>();
        final Document check = new Document()
                .append("name", checkModel.name)
                .append("command", checkModel.command)
                .append("id", checkModel.checkId)
                .append("description", checkModel.description)
                .append("topic", checkModel.topic)
                .append("last_output", checkModel.output)
                .append("index", index)
                .append("last_status", checkModel.status)
                .append("values", getCheckValues(checkModel,idx))
                .append("refresh", checkModel.refresh);
        checks.add(check);

        Document client = new Document()
                .append("name", checkModel.client)
                .append("checks", checks);
        //.append("$addToSet" , new Document("checks", checks)); // <<- error here '$addToSet' is not recocnized 

        db.getCollection("clients") // execute client insert or update
                .updateOne(
                        new Document().append("_id", checkModel.client), new Document("$set", client), new UpdateOptions().upsert(true)
                );
    }

    static int index = 0;

    // Name of the topic from which we will receive messages from = " testt"
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName);

        CheckModel checkModel = new CheckModel();
        checkModel.command = "ls -lA";
        checkModel.client = "client_001";
        checkModel.description = "ls -l command";
        checkModel.checkId = "lsl_command";
        checkModel.name = "client 001";
        checkModel.output = "result of ls -l";
        checkModel.status = 0;
        checkModel.topic = "basic_checks";
        checkModel.refresh = 5000;

        initDB(db);
        // insert the first check
        insertCheck(db, checkModel);
        // insert the second check after some modification
//        insertCheck(db, modifyData(checkModel));

    }
    // mdofiy data to test the check
    private static CheckModel modifyData(CheckModel checkModel){
        checkModel.status = 1;
        checkModel.output = "ls commadn not found";
        return checkModel;
    }
    private static void initDB(MongoDatabase db) {
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("configuration");
        if (collection.count() == 0) {
            Document b = new Document()
                    .append("_id", "app_config")
                    .append("historical_data", 20)
                    .append("current_index", 0);
            collection.insertOne(b);
        }

        Document b = new Document().append("none", "none");

        MongoCollection<Document> clients = db.getCollection("clients");
        clients.insertOne(b);
        clients.deleteOne(b);

        MongoCollection<Document> topics = db.getCollection("topics");
        topics.insertOne(b);
        topics.deleteOne(b);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use $push, $each, $slice to solve your problem, see alse https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/.

db.students has following documents

```
{ "_id" : 10, "scores" : [  1, 2, 3 ] }

db.students.update(
   { _id: 10 },
   {
     $push: {
       scores: {
       $each: [ 4 ],
       $slice: -3
     }
   }
 }
)
```

result is:

```
{ "_id" : 10, "scores" : [  2, 3, 4] }
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but that not what I'm searching.??!